# How to display names from KML file in google-earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, display

I exported via QGIS a .shp file in .kml. Labels are displayed without any problem in QGIS from a field "REG_NAMES". Now I want to display these names on GGearth from the .kml, but it does not work.

In the question of Pravin Kumar it was said to associate, in the export windows, to "names" the field that you want, so here "REG_NAMES".

I wrote "REG_NAMES" in the field "names" of the Export windows of QGIS, but it does not display the names in GGEarth from the generated .kml. When I click on a polygon, all the informations are displayed in a small windows, but I just want the names to be always displayed on the map

Comment: Have a look at your kml file with a text editor. If you've set up the export correctly then you should see your data - previously in the field REG_NAMES - now appears as shown here (instead of [data]): <name>[data]</name> - another way to work out what's going wrong is to create a simple kml file from Google Earth, then open this also in a text editor. Look to see what the differences are. A simple KML file will look something like what's shown in this link: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#basic_kml